# SqlDataAdapter .update Function not updating

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have One Table Call RSN_ALl in  Sql database
, I want to Updates its few row by my XML file,based On RSN column Primary key.

I try By sqlcommnadBuilder and other way but its not updating.

Noted: In XMl file I have 2 or 3 rows which have Same "RSN" value as DataBase but other Columns Values are Different Which I need to Update 
I Got Exception as

> Update requires a valid InsertCommand when passed DataRow
>   collection with new rows.

And When I use CommandBuilder I got Exception as

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_RSN_All'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.RSN_All'.
>   The statement has been terminated.

but this Rows Already Present in Sql DataBase TAble

```
using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(SqlHelper.ConString))
{
    DataSet DsXmlData = new DataSet();                                 
    DsXmlData.ReadXml(xml_file_path);
    DsXmlData.Tables["RSN_ALL"].PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { DsXmlData.Tables["RSN_ALL"].Columns["RSN"] };

    using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from RSN_All", cn))
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);  

        string updataCommand ="update RSN_All set Batch_M_id = @Batch_M_id ,Parent_RSN =@Parent_RSN, Pkg_Location =@Pkg_Location, CompanyId =@CompanyId where RSN =@RSN";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(updataCommand, cn);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Batch_M_id", SqlDbType.BigInt, 0, "Batch_M_id");
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Parent_RSN", SqlDbType.VarChar , 20, "Parent_RSN");
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Pkg_Location", SqlDbType.NVarChar , 100, "Pkg_Location");
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@CompanyId", SqlDbType.Int , 0, "CompanyId");
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@RSN", SqlDbType.VarChar , 20, "RSN");
        da.UpdateCommand = cmd;

        da.Update(DsXmlData.Tables["RSN_ALL"] );
    }
}
```

Comment: You get any exception or error message? What is your `cmd` looks like after you add parameters?

Comment: I got Exception which I mention in my Question And My cmd looks like  ="update RSN_All set Batch_M_id = @Batch_M_id ,Parent_RSN =@Parent_RSN, Pkg_Location =@Pkg_Location, CompanyId =@CompanyId where RSN =@RSN" means somehow it didnt replace paramenters values from its names

Comment: Are you adding values to your parameters??

Comment: m i miss any step for assign value to this parameters ??
my both dataset  DsXmlData and ds filled, and having these column,
as per My knowledge this da.update its sufficient for assign values to the parameters

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(SqlHelper.ConString))
{
    DataSet DsXmlData = new DataSet();                                 
    DsXmlData.ReadXml(xml_file_path);
    DsXmlData.Tables["RSN_ALL"].PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { DsXmlData.Tables["RSN_ALL"].Columns["RSN"] };

    using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from RSN_All", cn))
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "RSN_ALL");  

        string updataCommand ="update RSN_All set Batch_M_id = @Batch_M_id ,Parent_RSN =@Parent_RSN, Pkg_Location =@Pkg_Location, CompanyId =@CompanyId where RSN =@RSN";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(updataCommand, cn);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Batch_M_id", SqlDbType.BigInt, 0, "Batch_M_id");
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Parent_RSN", SqlDbType.VarChar , 20, "Parent_RSN");
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Pkg_Location", SqlDbType.NVarChar , 100, "Pkg_Location");
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@CompanyId", SqlDbType.Int , 0, "CompanyId");
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@RSN", SqlDbType.VarChar , 20, "RSN");
        da.UpdateCommand = cmd;

        da.Update(ds, "RSN_ALL");
    }
}
```